# Calculate the number of occurrences of the text in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Calculate the number of occurrences of the text, “university”, anywhere in the
"School" field for each day in the 15 day period between 2018-12-15 to 2018-12-31?

Can someone help me with this query? I am working on a redshift environment.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied any information about the table, but the query would probably be similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
  date_field,
  COUNT(*) as qty
FROM table
WHERE
  school ILIKE '%university%' AND
  date_field BETWEEN '2018-12-15' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY date_field
ORDER BY date_field
```

This counts the number of rows containing a case-insensitive `university` where a date field is between the indicated dates. This assumes that `date_field` is a `DATE`, not a `TIMESTAMP`.